# Unity UnityScript errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm following a "MoveAround" UnityScript tutorial on Unity3d. The problem is the code the instructor wrote works fine when he drags and drops the script onto the object, yet when I do the same, I get these errors messages:

```
Unknown identifier: 

 line 14 'Speed' (BCE0005) and 

 line 15'Curspeed'
```

The code is EXACTLY the same as the tutorial displays:

```
1
2 var speed = 3.0;
3 var rotateSpeed = 3.0;
4
5 function Update ()
6 {
7    var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
8    
9   // Rotate around y - axis
10  transform.Rotate(0, Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")* rotateSpeed, 0);
11    
12  // Move forward / backward
13  var forward = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);  
14  var CurSpeed = Speed * Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");   Unknown identifier:'Speed' BCE0005
15  controller.SimpleMove(forward * curspeed);        Unknown identifier:'Curspeed' BCE0005
16 }
17    
18 @script RequireComponent(CharacterController)
```

Answer (score 3):

Case matters in most programming languages. You use `speed` in your variable declaration and `Speed` later on, those are two different things.

The same applies to `CurSpeed` and `curspeed`.

Decide on one way to write each one and be consistent (personally I'd suggest `speed` and `curSpeed`).